# Google Maps V3 doesn't remove event listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, listener

I have a problem with Google Maps API v3. I'm trying to remove a mouseover listener when zoom changes.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myOptions = {
        ...
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    function colormaps(map) {
        var newmap = map;
        var piemonteCoords = [
            ...
        ];        
        var piemontePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            ...
        });         
        piemontePolygon.setMap(newmap);
        google.maps.event.addListener(piemontePolygon, 'mouseover', function(event) {
            var prova = event;
            showInfo(prova, newmap, 'Italy');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newmap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
            if (zoomLevel >= 6) {
                google.maps.event.clearListeners(newmap, 'mouseover');
            }
            else {
                ...
            }
        } //fine colormaps
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', colormaps(map));
    });
```

When zoom reaches the target level, the listener is not removed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're adding listener to `piemontePolygon` object, but you're clearing it from `newmap` object, which probably is wrong (I'm not an expert in that area so I can't be sure).

Try doing it like:

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(piemontePolygon, 'mouseover');
```

**EDIT:**
According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1#removing) you could try it with another approach, if the above code fails.

Case 1 (you could pass an event type as a second argument as well):

```
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(piemontePolygon);
```

Case 2:

```
var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(piemontePolygon, 'mouseover', function(
    var prova = event;
    showInfo(prova, newmap, 'Italy')
});

google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
```

Comment: +1 Case 2 is the way to go, the most explicit way to understand what is happening.

Comment: thanks all for your answer... the first solution works, the second not.

Comment: Shame google didn't do it the (imo) more logical way -  `google.maps.event.removeListener(obj, ['event'], [optional callback])` - the 2nd and 3rd param being optional for more specificity