# Check for checkbox value after Google Map has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I *think* I'm missing something basic about javascript. I could use your help!

**Scenario:** After clicking "search" the google map loads. As it loads, a checkbox appears that says, "Redo results when map is moved" (similar to yelp). If the map is dragged or zoomed, the results update. That part works fine.

**Problem:** The value of the `checkbox` (true or false) is recognized by the `redo()` function when the map loads, and it doesn't check it again after that (because even though `redo()` is updating the results it's not reloading the map). So if you toggle the checkbox, the "redo" function doesn't notice!

**Simplified Code:**

```
//HAML
%input{:type => "checkbox", :id => "followCheck", :name => "followCheck", :onclick => 'handleClick();'}

//load the map
function showLocations() { 
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    bunch of map stuff;
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    redo(); //this is the redo function, see below
  }
}

function handleClick(checkbox) {
  var chk = document.getElementById("followCheck").checked;
  console.log("checkbox value is currently " + chk);
  return chk;
}

function redo() {
  var chk = handleClick();
  console.log("inside redo, value is " + chk);
   if (chk == true) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function() {
       mapAdjusted = 1;
       updateMapAfterUserInteraction();
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
       mapAdjusted = 1;
       updateMapAfterUserInteraction();
     });
   }
}
```

(note, that redo() function was written by my collaborator, who is smarter than me and currently out of town.)

So, `Redo()` loads when the map loads. If the checkbox is true when the map loads, then the `redo()` function processes `zoom/drag`. But it still does it even after changing the value to false (and if the value is false when the page loads, the opposite happens).

What is needed to get `redo()` to see that the value has changed? `push()`? `bind()`? get/set? `change()`? `addEventListener()`? Should I reload the map when the checkbox is toggled (I'd rather not)? A whole new approach? I'm stuck! Thanks. I'm open to JQuery ideas, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. First off, with a small adjustment to the function I was able get it to turn ON after checking the box (even if the results loaded while the box was unchecked via a previous page session). Here is that code (I actually found like three variations that all had the same result):

```
function redo() {
  if ($("#followCheck").is(':checked')) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function() {
      mapAdjusted = 1;
      updateMapAfterUserInteraction();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      mapAdjusted = 1;
      updateMapAfterUserInteraction();
    });
  }
}
```

The problem was that it didn't turn off. And that's because I've added two listeners! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333411/3931390) helped me remove the listeners. Note that (for me) it only worked when the `removeListener()` function is within the `addListener()` function. Kind of strange.

```
function redo() {
  var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function() {
    if (!$("#followCheck").is(':checked')) {
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
    } else {
      mapAdjusted = 1;
      updateMapAfterUserInteraction();
    }
  });
  var listener2 = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed',  function() {
    if (!$("#followCheck").is(':checked')) {
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener2);
    } else {
      mapAdjusted = 1;
      updateMapAfterUserInteraction();
    }
  });
}
```

Oh and I also changed `onclick()` to `onchange()`